# How to pause/interupt with keyboard

Tags: python-3.x, audio, wav, vlc

I'm using the following script to play all the WAV files in the current path. I will be modifying it to print the output of some text files. That part is easy.

Need to know how/where in the loop of playing the WAV files, where to add some code to pause/interupt the execution of the code with the keyboard.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import vlc
import time
import glob

wav_files = glob.glob("*.wav")
instance=vlc.Instance(["--no-sub-autodetect-file"])

# You should not recreate a player for each file, just reuse the same 
# player
player=instance.media_player_new()

for wav in wav_files:
    player.set_mrl(wav)
    player.play()
    playing = set([1,2,3,4])
    time.sleep(5) #Give time to get going
    duration = player.get_length() / 1000
    mm, ss = divmod(duration, 60)
    print("Playing", wav, "Length:", "%02d:%02d" % (mm,ss))
    while True:
        state = player.get_state()
        if state not in playing:
            break
        continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steal the `getch` right out of `vlc.py`
I've added the windows option, as you didn't specify an OS.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import vlc
import time
import glob
import sys
import termios, tty

try:
    from msvcrt import getch  # try to import Windows version
except ImportError:
    def getch():  # getchar(), getc(stdin)  #PYCHOK flake
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(fd)
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old)
        return ch

wav_files = glob.glob("*.wav")
print("Play List")
for f in wav_files:
    print(f)
instance=vlc.Instance(["--no-sub-autodetect-file"])

# You should not recreate a player for each file, just reuse the same
# player
player=instance.media_player_new()

for wav in wav_files:
    player.set_mrl(wav)
    player.play()
    playing = set([1,2,3,4])
    time.sleep(1) #Give time to get going
    duration = player.get_length() / 1000
    mm, ss = divmod(duration, 60)
    print("Playing", wav, "Length:", "%02d:%02d" % (mm,ss))
    while True:
        state = player.get_state()
        if state not in playing:
            break
        k = getch()
        if k in ["N","n"]:#Next
            player.stop()
            break
        elif k in ["Q","q"]:#Quit
            player.stop()
            sys.exit()
            break
        elif k == " ":#Toggle Pause
            player.pause()
        else:
            print("[Q - Quit, N - Next, Space - Pause]")
        continue
```

Comment: Thanks, that work perfectly. I use Linux/Kubuntu and didn't change the code you supplied. Just copied it and tested it. Used space bar to pause/go, .. brilliant, just what I wanted, thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4637585/rolf-of-saxony -  I did use the 'up arrow' to say this answer is useful, but I don't have enough points for it to show. Just saying, ..know you are appreciated.  :)